# Difference Between HWI and "HiveServer" in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am going through Apache Hive these days and the following thing is confusing me quite a bit -

1. There is a Hive Web Interface (hive --service hwi), that listens on a port (default 9999) and allow the client to Submit a query and come back later facility, Authorization equipped etc.
2. There is also a HiveServer (hive --service HiveServer), that runs a server and allows remote clients to connect and submit Hive queries and is also Authorization protected etc.

How are they different ?    (OR are they not) ?   If they are different, but offers the same kind of features, what is different ?

There is also a HiveServer2 and a Thrift server, which not sure but I think an improvement over HiveServer ?

Can someone talk about them and clarify, whats the uniqueness in them and bigger problem they solve ?

Regards,

(*Vipul)() ;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### HWI

Hive's HWI (HiveWebInterface) is an alternative to using Hive command line interface. It provides the features such as:

- Schema browsing
- Detached query execution
- Manage sessions
- No local installation

#### HiveServer

HiveServer on the other hand allows remote clients to submit requests to Hive using [Thrift](https://thrift.apache.org)'s [various programming language](https://thrift.apache.org/lib/) bindings. As HiveServer uses Thrift, it is sometimes called as ThriftServer.

HiveServer v1 cannot handle concurrent requests from more than one client, this limitation is addressed in HiveServer v2, which allows multiple concurrent connections to clients. HiveServer2 also provides:

- authentication using Kerberos & LDAP
- SSL encryption
- PAM

HiveServer2 provides various [client interfaces](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveServer2+Clients) like:

- Beeline command line shell
- JDBC
- Python & Ruby clients

HiveServer2 JDBC driver can be used to connect to BI tools like Tableau, Talend, etc. to perform ETL.

Comment: Thanks Ashrith for responding. So that means there is no separate Hive thrift server and HiveServer2 itself is the Thrift server. Where can I get the JDBC driver to connect to HiveServer2 ?

Comment: Yes, HiveServer2 is also called as ThriftServer. JDBC driver is part of HiveServer2 and here is a link on [how to use it](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveServer2+Clients#HiveServer2Clients-JDBC).

Comment: Could some one explain what is the concurrent connection. Even with Hive CLI multiple connections can be made from edge node to Hiveserver.